# AXLSX Gem: Style group of cells of a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, axlsx

I'm referring to [THIS LINK](https://gist.github.com/randym/3980434#gistcomment-660038) for surrounding a box (bunch of columns) using the gem. I could figure out how to add border top and bottom, to a group of cells. Eg:

```
sheet["B3:D3"].each do |cell|
  cell.style = workbook.styles.add_style({:border => { :style => :thick, :color => '000000', :name => :top, :edges => [:top] }})
end

sheet["B24:D24"].each do |cell|
  cell.style = workbook.styles.add_style({:border => { :style => :thick, :color => '000000', :name => :bottom, :edges => [:bottom] }})
end
```

Now the problem comes when I'm trying to add left and right columns on **empty** cells. Eg:

```
sheet["B3:B24"].each do |cell|
  cell.style = workbook.styles.add_style({:border => { :style => :thick, :color => '000000', :name => :left, :edges => [:left] }})
end

sheet["D3:D24"].each do |cell|
  cell.style = workbook.styles.add_style({:border => { :style => :thick, :color => '000000', :name => :right, :edges => [:right] }})
end
```

I get error:

> NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

for `sheet["B3:B24"]`

The reason being, the empty cell in the given range. Eg:

Cells like `B5` and `B6` are empty and when I do `sheet["B3:B24"]`, I get the above error
But, if I do, `sheet["B7:B9"]` or `sheet["B21:B24"]`, I don't get the error, as they are not empty

[image]

**NOTE:-** My box's columns start from B3 to B24. And rows from B3 to D3

**How can I add left and right border to a group of cells in a column?**

Answer (score 0):

Filling all the empty cells with a blank `space`, helped me go around the issue.